# Does moving towards an enemy with a reach weapon provoke an attack of opportunity?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e

If a character is 10 ft. from an enemy wielding Reach weapon, does moving five feet closer into their threatened area provoke an attack of opportunity?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the attacker [threatens](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/space-reach-threatened-area-templates) the square in question and the mover is moving more than just taking a [5 foot step](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Take-5-Foot-Step), then yes.

If the mover is just taking a 5 foot step, or that square is not threatened by the attacker, then no.

For further [reading](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Attacks-of-Opportunity).

Comment: To be clear, the "square in question" is the starting square.  AOOs occur when you *leave* a threatened square with a move action, not when you enter one.  Also, though the templates make this clear, it might be worth noting that [reach weapons do not threaten adjacent squares](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons#wpn-quality-reach).

Comment: I would add that there are other methods to avoid this AoO from Reach- what comes to mind are the Spring Attack and Ride-by Attack feats; both indicate that you don't provoke from the target for your movement. Another important note- you don't provoke multiple AoO from the same movement (ie if a Large creature with a Reach weapon threatens 15 and 20ft away, you only provoke when moving from 20ft to 15ft, not when you continue from 15 to 10 or closer).